# How to remove last file after new file saved in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using Django Ajax to update user avatar.What I want is after saving the new avatar ,system will delete the old one, because I want to each user only have one avatar stored in database to save space.

Here is my views.py:

```
def user_detail(request, username):
    profile_user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    form = UserAvatar(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request, 'user/user_detail.html', {

        'profile_user': profile_user,
        'form': form,
    })
```

forms.py:

```
class UserAvatar(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['avatar']
```

Models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    nickname1 = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='昵称')
    url = models.URLField('个人网址', blank=True, help_text='提示：网址必须填写以http开头的完整形式')
    avatar = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='avatars/', verbose_name='头像',
                                 processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 100)], 
                                 format='JPEG', 
                                 options={'quality': 95}  
                                 , blank=True, null=True
                                 )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = '用户信息'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name  
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: One way I would think of, is to override the save method. 

Check if the new post has an image and the current record has an imagen as well, then delete the current image finally super().save.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by myself:

models.py:

```
# delete
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=User)
def delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
    instance.avatar.delete(False)


# update
@receiver(post_init, sender=User)
def file_path(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance._current_file = instance.avatar


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def delete_old_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, '_current_file'):
        if instance._current_file != instance.avatar.path:
            instance._current_file.delete(save=False)
```